# how to replace all the elements in a list that are equal to atom1 with atom2 using scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(DEFINE (replace atom1 atom2 alist)
  (COND
    ((NOT (LIST? alist)) #F)
    ;((LIST? atom1) #F)
    ;((LIST? atom2) #F)
    ((= (car alist) atom1) (cons atom2 (replace atom1 atom2 (cdr alist))))
    (ELSE (cons (car alist) (replace atom1 atom2 (cdr alist))))))
```

The program is supposed to replace all the elements in `alist` that are equal to `atom1` with `atom2`. For example, if I run `(replace 2 3 '(4 5 7 2 8 2 2))`, the result should be `(4 5 7 3 8 3 3)`. I kept getting the error message "car: expects a pair, given empty".
Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base case should be to check for an *empty* list. An empty list still tests true for `list?`. So the first condition should instead be `(null? alist)`.